# C# Maintaining old WCF in .NET5 with prior source code

Tags: c#, wcf, grpc, service-model

In the new .NET5, Support for WCF has now been removed.

I am wondering if it is possible to simply take all relevant source references from Microsofts source reference, and just compile it again in my C# project.

AKA, everything in the namespace of System.ServiceModel. Or is there other stuff that I would be missing too. Is there any nuget packages that already do this for me?
I would be surprised if nobody else has attempted doing something like this.

CoreWCF unfortunately for my project will not work, as my project uses NetNamedPipeBinding, which is not supported in it.

I have looked also into migrating code into gRPC, but it seems like it might be quite a timely task to convert all my code into using it.

Comment: You are not the first and won't be the last. Cannot your code stay on .NET Framework? Migrating to .NET Core should be a phased process and you cannot hurry.

Comment: I'm not migrating to .NET Core.  -- I'm migrating to .NET 5.       And only need it on windows machines

Comment: .NET 5 = .NET Core 5 if you don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

CoreWCF will be getting NetNamedPipe support at some point next year. There's a couple of tasks ahead of it in the queue, but it's a high priority item to complete in 2022.
Source: Self, as I'm one of the owners of the CoreWCF project.

Answer (score 0):

The original implementation of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) was only supported on Windows. However, there is a client port available from the .NET Foundation. It is entirely open source, cross platform, and supported by Microsoft. The core NuGet packages are listed below:

- [System.ServiceModel.Duplex](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Duplex)
- [System.ServiceModel.Federation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Federation)
- [System.ServiceModel.Http](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Http)
- [System.ServiceModel.NetTcp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.NetTcp)
- [System.ServiceModel.Primitives](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Primitives)
- [System.ServiceModel.Security](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ServiceModel.Security)

The community maintains the server components that complement the aforementioned client libraries. The GitHub repository can be found at CoreWCF. The server components are not officially supported by Microsoft. For an alternative to WCF, consider gRPC.

Source:[Windows Communication Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-5#windows-communication-foundation)

Comment: You are literally repeating the contents in the question if you read it again.